# Is there a closed representation of these two integrals?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

The first one is:

$$ \int _R^{\infty} k_l(\alpha r) \frac{r^{l+2}}{z^{l+1}} dr$$

$$ \int _R^{\infty} k_l(\alpha r) \frac{z^{l+2}}{r^{l-1}} dr$$

where $R > 0$, $k_l$ is the l-th [modified spherical bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedSphericalBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) and $l\in \mathbb{N}_0$, so pay attention r is actually for l=0 in the nominator!

Maybe somebody has an idea, how to find a closed form, cause I actually do not:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "answer" is at the bottom of the link you provided. The modified spherical Bessel functions of second kind satisfy:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{k_n(x)}{x} &= \frac{-1}{2n+1}\left[ k_{n-1}(x) - k_{n+1}(x)\right]\tag{1a}\\
k'_n(x)          &= \frac{-1}{2n+1}\left[ n k_{n-1}(x) + (n+1) k_{n+1}(x)\right]\tag{1b}
\end{align}$$

If one multiply $(1a)$ by $n+1$ and add it to $(1b)$, we get:
$$
x^{-(n+1)} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^{n+1} k_n(x) \right] = 
\left[ \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{n+1}{x} \right] k_n(x) =
-k_{n-1}(x)\\
$$
The means
$$\begin{align}
\int_{R}^{\infty}  k_{l}(ar) \frac{r^{l+2}}{z^{l+1}} dr
&= \frac{1}{a^{l+3}z^{l+1}}\int_{aR}^{\infty} k_{l}(x) x^{l+2} dx\\
&= \frac{1}{a^{l+3}z^{l+1}} \int_{aR}^{\infty}-\frac{d}{dx}\left[ k_{l+1}(x) x^{l+2} \right] dx\\ 
&=  \frac{1}{a^{l+3}z^{l+1}} \left[ -k_{l+1}(x)x^{l+2} \right]_{aR}^{\infty}\\
&=  k_{l+1}(aR) \frac{R^{l+2}}{a z^{l+1}} 
\end{align}$$

Similarly, if one multiply $(1a)$ by $n$ and subtract it from $(1b)$, we get:
$$
x^{n} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^{-n} k_n(x) \right] = 
\left[ \frac{d}{dx} - \frac{n}{x} \right] k_n(x) =
-k_{n+1}(x)\\
$$
This implies
$$\begin{align}
\int_{R}^{\infty}  k_{l}(ar) \frac{z^{l+2}}{r^{l-1}} dr
&= a^{l-2}z^{l+2} \int_{aR}^{\infty} k_{l}(x) x^{-(l-1)} dx\\
&= a^{l-2}z^{l+2} \int_{aR}^{\infty}-\frac{d}{dx}\left[ k_{l-1}(x) x^{-(l-1)} \right] dx\\ 
&= a^{l-2}z^{l+2} \left[ -k_{l-1}(x)x^{-(l-1)} \right]_{aR}^{\infty}\\
&=  k_{l-1}(aR) \frac{z^{l+2}}{a R^{l-1}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: great, thank you...it is impressive, what you notice